# Options for Integrating or developing a physical security solution (physical access control via in-house mobile apps [NFC/Bluetooh])

Tags: physical, bluetooth, physical-access, nfc

Our team is looking to either integrate or develop a physical security solution for a rather large campus.

Requirements:

Ability to either integrate (with reader/electronic lock hardware) from our mobile apps which would allow access control (over NFC/Bluetooth) to areas.

We will be writing to our already existing identity management api's and expanding them to support what we need to for this project.

We are looking to write our own mobile integrations with purchased hardware, since this functionality has to exist within our organization's already existing mobile apps we developed. (we haven't found a company that offers the level of integration we want... most of the solutions we see out there are fantastic, but require downloading the security company's mobile app, managing access control via their cloud resources, etc).

What reader/electronic door lock hardware can we buy to build this level of in-house integration with?

To summarize: we are looking to buy scanners/door locks with NFC/Bluetooth capability and write security integrations for access control through already existing mobile apps we have developed...

I realize product suggestions can be of bad taste on here, but I invite them for the sake of discussion in addition to solutions that companies offer.

Our team will be expanding to hire security professionals in this realm to assist, so you can save the "don't roll your own auth" type of answers and comments :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Send challenge to the app which generates MAC over the challenge and sends it back. Backend verifies the MAC and grants access. Revoke MAC key to revoke access.

Comment: @defalt Yes. We were thinking about a similar approach, however, we are having trouble sourcing the hardware that would support functionality like this.

Comment: To support offline access, send challenge to the app which then certifies the challenge and sends it back. If the root certificate matches with root of trust in terminal, grant access. To revoke access, keep certificate life span short which can be recertified only after valid student logs in.

Comment: Take a look at HID and their SEOS/iClass platform. That's the biggest vendor I know of that does this kind of access control. They also frequently white label their products.